# Why SSL certificate only works in Internet Explorer?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, ssl-certificate

I've configured my ASP.NET Core app to accept https and then deployed it to an IIS Server. Created a certificate with a key of 2048 bytes and I configured the bindings. Everything works fine in Internet Explorer but once I change to Firefox, Chrome, Edge etc, I get an error saying that it's not secure. The error that appears on the browser is NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. Note that the certificate common name is the same as my website (I've notice that it might have caused an issue if both names were different). I've already tried to configure my SSL Setting of by website (in the IIS Server) to ignore the SSL, but it still does not work. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've already tried to configure my SSL Setting of by website (in the IIS Server) to ignore the SSL, but it still does not work

You can't persuade clients (browsers) to ignore SSL/TLS issues by doing something on the server-side.

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. Note that the certificate common name is the same as my website (I've noticed that it might have caused an issue if both names were different).

It seems that you've forgotten to include in your certificate Subject Alternative Name (SAN). All modern browsers require to have a Common Name in the SAN. IE doesn't require it so that's why it's the only one where it works.

Here's more about that: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172626/chrome-requires-san-names-in-certificate-when-will-other-browsers-ie-follow

Comment: How can I add the SAN to my certificate? Do I have to create a new certificate? (I used a private PKI by the way)

Comment: @Sam yup it must be new one, it's something that you include in a CSR. If you're using OpenSSL to generate CSRs (`openssl req`) you can do that by adding this flag `-addext "subjectAltName = DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com" ` Note that you need to change the domain name in this flag.

Comment: I'm using the IIS server and the pki website. Can I do that from either of those?

Comment: @Sam how do you generate your certificate? What do you mean by pki website?

Comment: the microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services. The it has an option to add additional attributes, but I'm not sure how I should add

Comment: @Sam maybe this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ff625722(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_Security